# Appcelerator studio's debugger doesn't work

Tags: debugging, titanium, breakpoints, skip, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to use Appcelerator studio's debugger but when I run application in debug mode it skip all breakpoints. In debug view studio show "Running" instead of "Debugging". I've tried whit various version of node js, titanium sdk and appcelerator studio, in 3 different machine with 3 different OS.
Can anyone explain me how does it work? or how can I use breakpoints?

Thank you all for the answer!

Comment: Dumb question, but are you actually selecting "debug" when you execute the program?  Going into Debug view is not enough; you need to launch the application with "debug".  In the upper left-hand corner, there is a green "play" button.  Next to it is a dropdown that says "Run" by default.  Change it to "Debug", and then choose a device or simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Debugging_in_Studio

[image]

As mentioned in the doc, To launch a project in debug mode, first select the project in the Project Explorer view, then in the global toolbar, select **Debug** from the Launch Mode drop-down list and a device from the Target drop-down list. If the Launch Automatically option is enabled under the Target drop-down list, the application will be automatically launched after the target is selected. If not, you need to click the Launch button to start the build process.

Let me know if you still can't debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator is so buggy that the official answer to do something does not work 90% of the time. So to debug i had to follow the next steps:

- Just exactly on the line you want to debug add the following line:

> debugger;

- Put the emulator on debug
- After waiting the loading time debug and it stops where you want to
  debug.